# Interpolate datetimes to match size of another array

Tags: matlab, datetime, size, interpolation

I have two times: `Time_One`, `Time_Two`

I need to make `Time_One` the same size as `Time_Two` without deleting any of the existing times. First I convert them into serial date numbers and then interpolate them but it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

```
Time_One={'05-Apr-2017 12:06:00','05-Apr-2017 12:07:00','05-Apr-2017 12:08:00','05-Apr-2017 12:09:00','05-Apr-2017 12:10:00','05-Apr-2017 12:11:00','05-Apr-2017 12:12:00'};
Time_Two={'05-Apr-2017 12:06:30','05-Apr-2017 12:07:30','05-Apr-2017 12:08:30','05-Apr-2017 12:09:30','05-Apr-2017 12:10:30','05-Apr-2017 12:11:30','05-Apr-2017 12:12:30','05-Apr-2017 12:13:30','05-Apr-2017 12:14:30'};
A = datenum(Time_One)';
B= datenum(Time_Two)';
C=interp1(A,A,B);
D= datetime(C,'ConvertFrom','datenum');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your interpolation `interp1(A,A,B)` isn't doing anything for you, since you've specified `A` as the input and output of the interpolant.

Instead, I suggest you use a "dummy" x-axis for your interpolation.

```
C = interp1( linspace(0,1,numel(A)), A, linspace(0,1,numel(B)) );
```

This will keep your start and end times the same, and the interior points will keep the same spacing relative to each other.

Comment: In this way it fixes the size problem but I don't keep the actual time. For example: It goes from  20-Apr-2020 12:06:45   20-Apr-2020 12:07:30. '05-Apr-2017 12:07:00' is skipped.

Comment: @Aurela Can you provide more details about how you expect to change the size of the array and keep the elements the same? What should make up the difference?

Comment: Adding the difference in time that is missing at the beginning (or any part). The result can look like this: Time_One={ '05-Apr-2017 12:06:00','05-Apr-2017 12:06:30','05-Apr-2017 12:07:00','05-Apr-2017 12:07:30','05-Apr-2017 12:08:00','05-Apr-2017 12:09:00','05-Apr-2017 12:10:00',05-Apr-2017 11:10:00',05-Apr-2017 12:12:00'};

Comment: Can you assume the difference is always constant? This wasn't at all clear from your question...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I only want to add some more times in between the times that I already have to make it the same size as the other data. The difference as you see in the example before cannot be always constant.

Comment: If it's not always constant then I don't understand the logic you want to use to infill values. Please edit your question to mathematically define how you want the interpolation to work